# rails 4 backend and ios image upload

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to build a image upload buy can via web or ios app,I got a example https://github.com/defish16/ios-to-rails-images , and I use Rails 4

Model:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :avatar_data

has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { medium: ["300x300>", :png], thumb: ["100x100>", :png]}
belongs_to :project
before_save :decode_avatar_data

def decode_avatar_data
# If avatar_data is present, it means that we were sent an image over
# JSON and it needs to be decoded.  After decoding, the image is processed
# normally via Paperclip.
 if self.avatar_data.present?
    data = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(self.avatar_data))
    data.class.class_eval {attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type}
    data.original_filename = self.id.to_s + ".png"
    data.content_type = "image/png"

    self.avatar = data
 end
end

end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :avatars, class_name: 'Test', dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatars
end
```

Controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

def create
@project = Project.new(project_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @project.save
    format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, avatars_attributes: [:avatar])
end

class TestsController < ApplicationController

def create
@test = Test.new(test_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @test.save
    format.html { redirect_to @test, notice: 'Test was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @test }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @test.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def test_params
  params.require(:test).permit(:project, :avatar_data, :avatar)
end
```

I can get a normal upload via web, but when I try to upload via ios app I can't get the image

here is part of my logs

when I used ios app
Parameters: {"avatars_attributes"=>[{"avatar_data"=>"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QBYR.......

but in web
Parameters: {"project"=>{"name"=>"test3", "description"=>"teset3", "avatars_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"avatar"=>#

Is it a problem?Cuz in app avatars_attributes didn't in the "project", how can I fix it?in app or server
If not, Where would be a mistake??

Comment: Does it work on desktop? I see you're using `nested_attributes` which can cause issues. Does the upload work _at all_ ?

Comment: Yes,it is ok in web, only when I used ios app upload via json will cause some problem

Comment: OHhhhhh you're using JSON? That changes everything

Comment: Do you have your form code when using JSON?

Comment: https://github.com/booda406/server_test, here is my whole code, and project and test I used paperclip, post and image I used carrierwave,but I failed with both of them

Comment: so the action "create" will be different in json and html?

Comment: The create action does the same thing if it receives data from JSON or HTML.... but it's _how_ the data is sent to it that counts. The problem is that JSON might by-pass the Paperclip / Carrierwave process, which will cause your problem

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why this comment show up this morning, I have tried two ways, but both can't receive img data from ios app

Comment: defish16 uses Rails 3.2 and I think you should too. There are some differences between that version and Rails 4, since you are not very familiar with Ruby it would be smart to go with older version first.

Comment: Well.....but my company needs to do this in Rails 4...and Rails 4 isn't better in safe than Rails 3.2?

Answer (score 0):

You intend to decode a base64 image data url in your model, but seems there is no base64 data url in your view, I have a example to show how to convert image file to data url(use html5 file api, not working < IE10):

http://codepen.io/luckyyang/pen/BghJD

Comment: You should really explain your answers *in* your answers, not just with a link to the answer. That site might disappear, or change the way they generate urls, and then it would be completely useless to anyone.

Comment: Thanks for remind. It's just a example/live demo, those words is my explanation